# Ranking with multiple weights/ features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-engineering, moving-window

> We have entities where every entity has start ($s_i$) and end ($e_i$) times and count $c_i$. 
>   An entity is *important* if its interval ($e_i - s_i$) is large and if its $c_i$ is large.

**Here's what I did:**

In a time window $t$, we take the set of entities that are active (their interval intersect with our window), $entities_t$

Let's define:

$$S_t = \min_{i\in entities_t} s_i \\ E_t = \max_{i\in entities_t} e_i$$

So at time $t$ we can define the features:

$$i\in entities_t: a_{it} = \frac{e_i - s_i}{E_t - S_t}$$

Similarly, we can define:

$$C_t = \max_{i \in entities_t} c_i$$

and the corresponding features:

$$i\in entities_t: b_{it} = \frac{c_i}{C_t}$$

**What I'd like to achieve:**
I need to devise a formula which need to resemble "how many" *important* entities are within the time window.

- Are $a$ and $b$ good as features? If so, how to use them together?
- if not, how would you define them?
- I currently don't have quantitive way or some test to asses it, but the $a$ feature is "stronger" than the $b$ feature (In words, the time feature is stronger than the count).
- Given that, I'd probably need some hyper parameter to weight the two features, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by examining $a$ and $b$. $a$ is really a proportion of time, which runs from $0$ to $1$. If $a_{it} = 1$, then you have 1 (presumably important) entity in your time window. Likewise if $a_{it} = 0$, then presumably that particular entity is somewhat unimportant.

Similarly, $b$ is also a proportion running from $0$ to $1$, with a value of $1$ indicating one dominating (presumably important) entity, and $0$ indicating a presumably unimportant entity.

You can also assign a weight to $a$ and $b$ to adjust for the fact that $a$ matters more than $b$. Let's call those values $w_a$ and $w_b$. Let's make $w$ also between 0 and 1, so we can keep the notation nice.

Now, since $a$ and $b$ have the same support set, we can take a weighted average to get an measure of importance, let's call it $I$. Then

$I_{it} = w_a*a_{it} + w_b*b_{it}$

With $I$ running from $0$ to $1$. For each entity, if $I_{it}$ exceeds some predetermined value, then it is important.

Each timestamp would be assigned a count of how many important values it has.

**There is one immediate danger that I can see**

A time stamp with 1 important event either has one important event and a bunch of miniscule events, or 1 important event and no other events at all. Therefore, it may be worth keeping track of the ratio of important events to all events within a timeframe, so you have an idea which case you're in.

Hope this helps.